# What is the best way to share data between a web app and a iOS app?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, swift, core-data

Not looking for too many details here, I'm just wondering how to code an iOS app that accesses/modifies the same data that is used in a web app.

- Can this be done using CoreData?
- Can this be done with a MySQL db?
- Can this be done using MongoDB?

Do have any links where I could go to learn more about this?

Comment: To share the same data you only need to keep it in one place. No matter if text file, DB or anything else

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as too broad, but one way I use is a JSON <--> HTTPS <--> MySQL interface, with which both the iOS API and JavaScript APIs are quite happy to use.

Comment: Depends on the web app technology you are using and the amount of data you would want to share between them. But the question seems to broad to answer